# Choppy UI, stalling combox/menues etc (related to wpf and perhaps pen input in win 7)

Tags: wpf, user-interface, graphics

I have a strange issue with my computer when working with WPF-based applications (have only noticed it with WPF yet). The thing is that the UI sometimes gets very choppy while moving the cursor over elements with tooltips (as they are shown/hidden) or when opening comboboxes and menues. Sometimes it can freeze/stall for a couple of seconds before a combobox opens. I have a comp setup with a GeForce 250 (latest 01/07/11 drivers), 12 gb ram, intel xeon w3580, running 64-bit win 7. I also have activated Pen Input. Im however using the mouse, my wacom board is currently disconnected.

My first question is if anybody else have had these problems (ive checked on other computers with the same app and similar setup and cant find any problems there).

Secondly, if anybody have found a solution to it?

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the pen input (since its the only thing thats different, but its a longshot).

Clarification: Its not the animations thats choppy, the UI freezes completely for a second up to a couple of seconds when clicking on perhaps a combobox or when a tooltip is shown (not always).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved! It was not enough to disconnect and uninstall the wacom drivers. I had to stop and disable to Tablet Input Service in Windows Services as well. This solved all problems!